# How did slaves honoring their masters impact Paul’s doctrine?

Tags: 1-timothy

1 Timothy 6:1 NASB

> All who are under the yolk as slaves are to regard their own masters as worthy of all honor so that the name of God and our doctrine will not be spoken against.

How does slaves honoring their masters impact whether the name of God and Paul’s doctrine would be spoken against?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Honouring" them is actually about obeying them, which is the key to the relationship. He means that people would be saying to each other; "That teaching relating to the Christian God cannot be trusted, because slaves who believe in it are more likely to rebel against their owners. In fact that whole community is dangerous to the stability of society, and needs to be suppressed by authority."

Comment: Helpful answer! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

To the fine answer of @Stephen Disraeli above can be added that Paul tries to imprint in the faith of the believers the eternal dimension of freedom, that is not commensurate with dimension of the earthly institutions and which is possible only through liberation from sin and death, the task achievable only through Christ.

Now, such a liberation is possible for all social strata to the effect that a slave thus liberated, is a freeman of Christ 1 Cor. 7:22), while still remaining, socially speaking, a slave. Of course, if a slave-owner becomes a slave of Christ, being bought by His blood, and through this “slavery”, which in fact provides freedom from sin, is assimilated to Christ, then he will not oppress his own slaves, because Christ does not oppress anybody and neither does He wish to have slaves, but sees His followers as friends or potential friends.

Thus, even if the social situation is not changed, both a Christian slave-owner and his Christian slave can in principle be (sorry Karl Marx!) in a brotherly and friendly relationships in Christ, their common eternal Master.

Comment: Thank you for this addition!

Answer (score 0):

The name of the Lord is blasphemed due to our works when we fail to live up to our commitment to Him by not following His commands.

The word used is blasphemy. Throughout the Bible we see that believers bear the name of God. They are representatives of their God just as ethnicities represent their nation state, or students represent their schools. God is concerned about his reputation for being holy; he commands his people to be holy and perfect like him and not to defame his name among others, according to the doctrine. [Gotquestions](https://www.gotquestions.org/blasphemy-blaspheme.html) says on blasphemy:

> Followers of God are also responsible to make sure their behavior doesn’t incite others to blaspheme God. In Romans 2:17-24, Paul scolds those who claim to be saved through the law and yet still live in sin. Using Isaiah 52:5, Paul tells them, “God’s name is blasphemed among the Gentiles because of you” (verse 24). In 1 Timothy 1:20 Paul explains that he had abandoned two false teachers to Satan so they would “be taught not to blaspheme”; thus, promulgating false doctrine and leading God’s people astray is also a form of blasphemy

Followers are known from [their conduct](http://www.smartbiblesearch.com/droid/search_results2.php?p=1&v=AGKJBCDE&s=Your%20conduct%20should%20be&r=27580&qi=&i=&j=Y&l=JzF8OiAxIEMgTicyN0AgNSBKIE4nNUAgNSBNIFknUUIgMzAgQiBZ&e=Y), or a tree is known by its fruits:

> NASB Philippians 1:27 Only conduct yourselves in a manner worthy of the gospel of Christ, so that whether I come and see you or remain absent, I will hear of you that you are standing firm in one spirit, with one mind striving together for the faith of the gospel.

> 1 Peter 2:12 Keep your behavior excellent among the Gentiles, so that in the thing in which they slander you as evildoers, they may because of your good deeds, as they observe them, glorify God in the day of visitation.

> NLT Ezekiel 36:19-21: “I scattered them to many lands to punish them for the evil way they had lived. But when they were scattered among the nations, they brought shame on my holy name. For the nations said, ‘These are the people of the LORD, but he couldn’t keep them safe in his own land!’ Then I was concerned for my holy name, on which my people brought shame among the nations.”

> NHEB Colossians 3:22-25: “Servants, obey in all things those who are your masters according to the flesh, not just when they are looking, as people-pleasers, but in singleness of heart, fearing the Lord. And whatever you do, work heartily, as for the Lord, and not for people, knowing that from the Lord you will receive the reward of the inheritance; for you serve the Lord Christ. But he who does wrong will receive again for the wrong that he has done, and there is no partiality.”

> James 2:5-7: “Listen, my beloved brothers. Did not God choose those who are poor in this world to be rich in faith, and heirs of the kingdom which he promised to those who love him? But you have dishonored the poor person. Do not the rich oppress you, and personally drag you before the courts? Do not they blaspheme the honorable name by which you are called?”